# It is not displaying related modules in the drop down menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to set up 2 drop down menus, one for "Course" and the others for the related "Modules" with the course chosen.

Now the "Course" drop down menu works fine. The problem is the "Modules" drop down menu. If I select a course from the "Course" drop down menu, then it should display the modules related to the selected course in the "Modules" drop down menu. But instead it is only displaying the "Please Select" option for the "Modules" drop down menu, nothing else.

How can I get the related modules to appear in the "Modules" drop down menu?

Below is the code where it displays the "Course" drop down menu and the set up for the "Modules" drop down menu, it contains a jquery where it links to the "module.php" file where it will find and list the related modules as options in the "Module" drop down menu.

```
<?php

// connect to the database
include('connect.php');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
die();
}

$sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseName FROM Course"; 

$sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

$sqlstmt->execute(); 

$sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseName);

$courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

$courseHTML = "";  
$courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop" onchange="getModules();">'.PHP_EOL; 
$courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
{ 
$course = $dbCourseId;
$coursename = $dbCourseName; 
$courseHTML .= "<option value='".$course."'>" . $course . " - " . $coursename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  
} 

$courseHTML .= '</select>'; 
$courseHTML .= '</form>'; 

$moduleHTML = "";  
$moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
$moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 


?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getModules() { 
var course = jQuery("#CoursesDrop").val(); 
jQuery('#modulesDrop').empty(); 
jQuery('#modulesDrop').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>'); 
jQuery.ajax({ 
type: "post", 
url:  "module.php", 
data: { course:course }, 
success: function(response){ 
jQuery('#modulesDrop').append(response); 
} 
}); 


}

</script>
```

Below is the module.php page:

```
<?php

     // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

 /* check connection */
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
die();
}


$course = isset($_POST['course']) ? $_POST['course'] : ''; 

$sql = "
SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
c.CourseName,
m.ModuleName
FROM Course c
INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
WHERE
(c.CourseId = ?)
ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId
"; 

 $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

 $sqlstmt->bind_param("s",$course);

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 

 $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);


$moduleHTML  = "";  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
    $moduleHTML .= "<option value='$dbModuleId'>" . $dbModuleId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;   
} 


echo $moduleHTML; 

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the modules drop in a div and draw the SELECT tags as well

And it may be better to do it all as a jquery "load"

```
$moduleHTML .= '<div id="modulesDrop">';
$moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" >'.PHP_EOL; 
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
$moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 
$moduleHTML .= '</div>';
```

and

```
$moduleHTML .= "<select >";
 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
    $moduleHTML .= "<option value='$dbModuleId'>" . $dbModuleId . "</option>".PHP_EOL;   
} 
$moduleHTML .= "</select>";
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer but it is still not displaying the modules, I know the query is correct I as I tested the query but still not displaying modules in Modules drop down menu